# Holomorphic sections of holomorphic vector bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

If $G:E\rightarrow F$ is a holomorphic bundle map over a smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are two complex manifolds, there is a result that say that every local smooth section can be write as a combination of holomorphic sections. So, if $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$ are basis of holomorphic sections of $E$ and $F$ respectively we have, for all$x\in M$, $G(e_j(x))=\alpha^i_j(f_i(f(x)))$ for same functions $\alpha^i_j:M\rightarrow C$.

How can I show that this $\alpha^i_j$ are holomorphic functions?

Thanks for all help me.

Comment: Do you believe the statement you've written?

Comment: Which statement?

Comment: this one: "there is a result that say that every local smooth section can be write as a linear combination of holomorphic sections". Doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: Please, proofread what you wrote.  Your question starts with "If $F: E\to F$  is a holomorphic bundle map..." So, what is your $F$, is it a map or is it a bundle? Then in the same sentence you write "every local smooth section can be write". Every smooth local section of what? Of a holomorphic bundle? Then it would be utterly false. It would be saying that every smooth map is a linear combination of holomorphic maps, hence, is itself holomorphic, which is false, of course.

Comment: ok, right I change name's map. Instead I mean every local smooth section of a holomorphic bundle, yes. Sorry not linear combination but combination of holomorphic section multiplied by smooth functions.

Comment: OK, it is better. The next issue is the sentence "if $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$ are basis of holomorphic sections of $E$ and $F$ respectively": What is this supposed to mean? Do you mean "local sections over some open subset $U$ of the base"? And what do you mean by "basis"? Do you mean "bases as ${\mathcal O}_U$-modules, where ${\mathcal O}$ means the ring of holomorphic functions"?

Comment: Yes for both. Sorry.

Comment: Module on the sheaf of smooth complex functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite your actual question so it makes sense:

Suppose that $\xi: F\to N$ is a holomorphic vector bundle of finite rank $n$. Let $U\subset N$ be an open subset over which the bundle is holomorphically trivial, i.e. the restriction of the sheaf of holomorphic sections of $\xi$ to $U$ is free over the ring of holomorphic functions ${\mathcal O}_U$ with the basis $f_1,...,f_n$. In other words, the restriction $\xi_U$ of $\xi$ to $U$ is (holomorphically) isomorphic to the trivial bundle $U\times {\mathbb C}^n$ where the sections $f_1,...,f_n$ become the maps
$$
w\mapsto (w, \pi_i), i=1,...,n,
$$
where $\pi_i$ is the constant map (identically equal to $1$) to the $i$-factor of ${\mathbb C}^n$.

Suppose that $h$ is a smooth section of $\xi|_U$, i.e. a smooth map
$$
w\mapsto (w, \phi(w))\in U\times {\mathbb C}^n,
$$
i.e. $\phi=(\phi_1,...,\phi_n)$, where $\phi_i$'s are smooth complex-valued functions on $U$. (You are also assuming that $h$ comes from some smooth morphism of holomorphic vector bundles which is an irrelevant piece of information.)

You are then asking if there are smooth complex-valued functions $\alpha_1,...\alpha_n$ on $U$ such that
$$
h(w) =(w, \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i(w) \pi_i(w)).
$$
The answer is trivially positive: Take $\alpha_i=\phi_i$, $i=1,...,n$.

Comment: Thanks u. I also asked if, what u called $h$, is a holomorphic section then $\alpha_i$ are holomorphic function too? Sure if I take $\alpha_i=\phi_i$ but It is the only possibility? Or in general holomorphic function cannot be given by products of smooth functions and holomorphic functions?

Comment: @Uoff: Yes, holomorphic. And these would be unique.